# Receiving a 404 error on Get Request (MERN stack)

Tags: express

Currently I am trying to learn the MERN Stack, but I have difficulties to get it running.
I am always running into an 404 error, but, after hours of research, I could not fix it.
I would appreciate any help.

server/index.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

import usersRoutes from "./routes/users.route.js";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use("/users", usersRoutes);

const CONNECTION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://...";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on Port: http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

server/routes/users.route.js

```
import express from "express";
import UserModel from "../models/Users.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/getUsers", (req, res) => {
  UserModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});

export default router;
```

server/models/Users.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
export default UserModel;
```

Comment: Which URL are you retrieving?

Comment: http://localhost:3001/getUsers

Answer (score 0):

You are "mounting" your router here:

```
app.use("/users", usersRoutes);
```

This will match requests that are prefixed with `/users`.

Then you declare a route:

```
router.get("/getUsers", (req, res) => { … })
```

Because of the prefix, the URL for this route will be `/users/getUsers`.

If you want the URL to be `/getUsers`, leave out the prefix:

```
app.use(usersRoutes);
```